# How to set up website by configuring .htaccess and php so that it always displays the same page?

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I want the user to be shown the same php file when they open different webpages so that I look up the url and populate the webpage with the correct content.

For example
/Post/Page1 and /Post/Page2 will both show the same page /Post/index.php but the URL will remain in the full form. From the index.php I will have a code to look up the URL and query an SQL table to display the content that should actually be on that page.

/Otherlocations should remain unaffected.

I don't know where to get started here. Is this something that should be adjusted with the .htaccess file or with both .htaccess and php files?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: This is the classical router approach. You will find literally _thousands_ of existing tutorials and answers.